# Deducing the Equation of a Transformed Sinusoid

Tags: mathematical-physics, wave-equation

Given a wave, which you know to be a transformed sinusoid, how can you determine its equation?

I have the following, which is a wave I obtained experimentally:

[image]

It is a little off what we would expect theoretically, but I suppose there is only one equation (consisting of sinusoid[s]) that would represent such a wave form perfectly, almost like a trend line. How can I get the equation of that "trend line"?

Comment: Do you have a particular example you could show?

Comment: Do you mean that you just have data points $x_i,y_i$ ? As  imranfat commented, it would be a good idea you add   a particular example in the post.

Comment: Edited. Any ideas now?